# How to write an efficient bash script to modify a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have created a script to modify a CSV file, but it does not work correctly:

1. The `awk -F, 'NR==1|` does not print the header but the second row.
2. Even though there are only some columns specified in `while read V0 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V14 V15 V16` it prints out all columns of the csv.

**Some sample data:**

```
COUNTRY NAME,YEAR,LIFE LADDER,LOG GDP PER CAPITA,SOCIAL SUPPORT,HEALTHY LIFE EXPECTANCY AT BIRTH,FREEDOM TO MAKE LIFE CHOICES,GENEROSITY,PERCEPTIONS OF CORRUPTION,POSITIVE AFFECT,NEGATIVE AFFECT,CONFIDENCE IN NATIONAL GOVERNMENT,DEMOCRATIC QUALITY,DELIVERY QUALITY,STANDARD DEVIATION OF LADDER BY COUNTRY-YEAR,STANDARD DEVIATION/MEAN OF LADDER BY COUNTRY-YEAR,GINI INDEX (WORLD BANK ESTIMATE),GINI INDEX (WORLD BANK ESTIMATE) AVERAGE 2000-16","GINI OF HOUSEHOLD INCOME REPORTED IN GALLUP BY WP5-YEAR","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED GALLUP","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED WVS ROUND 1981-1984","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED WVS ROUND 1989-1993","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED WVS ROUND 1994-1998","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED WVS ROUND 1999-2004","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED WVS ROUND 2005-2009","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED WVS ROUND 2010-2014"
AFGHANISTAN,2008,3.72,7.16,0.45,50.79,0.71,0.17,0.88,0.51,0.25,0.61,-1.92,-1.65,1.77,0.47,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
AFGHANISTAN,2009,4.40,7.33,0.55,51.20,0.67,0.20,0.85,0.58,0.23,0.61,-2.04,-1.63,1.72,0.39,NULL,NULL,0.44,0.28,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
AFGHANISTAN,2010,4.75,7.38,0.53,51.59,0.60,0.13,0.70,0.61,0.27,0.29,-1.99,-1.61,1.87,0.39,NULL,NULL,0.32,0.27,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
AFGHANISTAN,2011,3.83,7.41,0.52,51.91,0.49,0.17,0.73,0.61,0.26,0.30,-1.91,-1.61,1.78,0.46,NULL,NULL,0.33,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
AFGHANISTAN,2012,3.78,7.51,0.52,52.24,0.53,0.24,0.77,0.71,0.26,0.43,-1.84,-1.40,1.79,0.47,NULL,NULL,0.34,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
AFGHANISTAN,2013,3.57,7.52,0.48,52.56,0.57,0.07,0.82,0.62,0.27,0.48,-1.87,-1.40,1.22,0.34,NULL,NULL,0.30,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
AFGHANISTAN,2014,3.13,7.51,0.52,52.88,0.50,0.11,0.87,0.53,0.37,0.40,-1.77,-1.31,1.39,0.44,NULL,NULL,0.41,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
AFGHANISTAN,2015,3.98,7.50,0.52,53.20,0.38,0.08,0.88,0.55,0.33,0.26,-1.84,-1.29,2.16,0.54,NULL,NULL,0.59,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
```

**This is my script:**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

INPUT=./happiness.csv.1
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }


while read V0 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V14 V15 V16 

do
      awk -F, 'NR==1 || /^[A-Z,a-z]*,2018/' | 
      grep '^.*-.*$' 
                                                
done < $INPUT
```

**And this is the output:**

```
> AFGHANISTAN,2008,3.72,7.16,0.45,50.79,0.71,0.17,0.88,0.51,0.25,0.61,-1.92,-1.65,1.77,0.47,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
> AFGHANISTAN,2018,2.69,7.49,0.50,52.59,0.37,-0.08,0.92,0.42,0.40,0.36,NULL,NULL,1.40,0.52,NULL,NULL,0.29,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
> ALGERIA,2018,5.04,9.55,0.79,65.90,0.58,-0.17,0.75,0.59,0.29,NULL,NULL,NULL,1.97,0.39,NULL,0.27,0.66,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.10,NULL,0.17
> ARGENTINA,2018,5.79,9.80,0.89,68.80,0.84,-0.20,0.85,0.82,0.32,0.26,NULL,NULL,2.47,0.42,NULL,0.46,0.40,NULL,0.27,0.22,0.17,0.15,0.17,0.19
> ARMENIA,2018,5.06,9.11,0.81,66.90,0.80,-0.14,0.67,0.58,0.45,0.67,NULL,NULL,2.10,0.41,NULL,0.31,0.40,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.23,NULL,NULL,0.10
> AZERBAIJAN,2018,5.16,9.67,0.78,65.5,0.77,-0.25,0.56,0.59,0.19,0.83,NULL,NULL,1.86,0.36,NULL,0.21,0.26,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.19,NULL,NULL,0.14
> BANGLADESH,2018,4.49,8.22,0.70,64.30,0.90,-0.03,0.70,0.54,0.36,0.83,NULL,NULL,2.15,0.47,NULL,0.32,0.36,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.20,0.23,NULL,
> BELARUS,2018,5.23,9.77,0.90,66.09,0.64,-0.18,0.71,0.45,0.23,0.42,NULL,NULL,1.69,0.32,NULL,0.28,0.29,NULL,NULL,0.25,0.22,NULL,NULL,0.32
> BELGIUM,2018,6.89,10.67,0.92,72,0.80,-0.12,0.63,0.74,0.25,0.44,NULL,NULL,1.54,0.22,NULL,0.28,0.29,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
> BOLIVIA,2018,5.91,8.86,0.82,63.59,0.86,-0.08,0.78,0.74,0.38,0.39,NULL,NULL,2.20,0.37,NULL,0.52,0.45,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
> BOTSWANA,2018,3.46,9.68,0.79,58.90,0.81,-0.25,0.80,0.72,0.26,0.71,NULL,NULL,2.63,0.76,NULL,0.62,0.61,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
> BRAZIL,2018,6.19,9.55,0.88,66.40,0.75,-0.12,0.76,0.74,0.34,0.16,NULL,NULL,2.63,0.42,NULL,0.54,0.42,NULL,NULL,0.06,NULL,NULL,0.09,0.07
> BULGARIA,2018,5.09,9.87,0.92,66.80,0.72,-0.17,0.95,0.63,0.18,0.21,NULL,NULL,2.03,0.39,NULL,0.35,0.34,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.23,NULL,0.19,
> BURUNDI,2018,3.77,6.54,0.48,53.40,0.64,-0.01,0.59,0.66,0.36,NULL,NULL,NULL,2.81,0.74,NULL,0.36,0.68,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
> CHILE,2018,6.43,10.06,0.89,69.90,0.78,-0.07,0.81,0.83,0.27,0.33,NULL,NULL,2.15,0.33,NULL,0.49,0.43,NULL,NULL,0.22,0.21,0.22,0.12,0.12
> CHINA,2018,5.13,9.69,0.78,69.30,0.89,-0.17,NULL,0.85,0.18,NULL,NULL,NULL,2.26,0.44,NULL,0.42,0.53,NULL,NULL,0.59,0.50,0.54,0.49,0.61
```

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Could I exchange the awk statement to something like:

```bash
while read V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 ....

do
      if [[ "$V2" = "2018" ]];then
```

Comment: I think this is the same question earlier where I said it needs a real parser because one of the field values have commas. E.g. `Most people can be trusted, Gallup`

Comment: @konsolebox I have solved this and cleaned the sample data, but the issue remains the same. The NR==1 prints the second row, and an incorrect amount of columns is being printed. Any other ideas?

Comment: You're mixing processing the file with a `while read` loop and with `awk`, in incompatible ways. The `read` reads the first line, then `awk` reads the rest of the file starting at line 2. Also, it looks like you're thinking that `read ... V10 V14 V15 ...` will skip fields 11 through 13, but it won't; it'll just assign field 11 to `V14`, field 12 to `V15`, etc.

Comment: What does `grep '^.*-.*$'` even do, and why not place it in awk originally.

Comment: @konsolebox  I want to get only the rows that contain negative values.

Comment: So `awk -F, 'NR==1 || /^[A-Z,a-z]*,2018/ && /-/'`?

Comment: @konsolebox thank you! Thank works perfectly. Could you help me understand how to include the header in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the current intent of your code, this is the modification I can suggest:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

INPUT=./happiness.csv.1
[[ -f $INPUT ]] || { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
awk -F, 'NR == 1 || $2 == "2018" && /-/' "$INPUT"
```